# Batch insert/update using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone give me a sample script for batch insert/update of records in table using stored procedure in SQL Server?

Comment: Batch update of what? What data source? Why a stored procedure?

Comment: I want a stored procedure script in Ms Sql to create a batch insert/update of records to particular table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done something like this in the past:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProductIds(@ProductIds xml) AS

INSERT INTO Product (ID) 
SELECT ParamValues.ID.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)')
FROM   @ProductIds.nodes('/Products/id') as ParamValues(ID) 

END
```

Obviously this is just a single-column table, but the XML approach applies for multi-column tables as well. You then do this:

```
EXEC InsertProductIds @ProductIds='<Products><id>3</id><id>6</id></Products>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending a table value parameter is another option.

SQL

```
CREATE TYPE TestTableType AS TABLE 
(
    ID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(100), 
    Description NVARCHAR(2000)
);
GO
CREATE proc [dbo].[Test_Table_Parameter]
    @Tbl TestTableType READONLY
as
    SELECT 'Return'
GO
```

Code

```
var param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@Tbl";
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var str = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" + DateTime.Now;

    //map the fields to datatypes here
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {i + 1, (i + 1).ToString(), str });
    }

    param.Value = dt;
```

These were taken from [here](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html) which also looks at performance of this and the xml approach on the SQL query end.

[This](http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-Test-for-the-cost-of-passing-parameters-to-a-SqlServer-2008-Stored-Procedure-as-XML-vs-Table-vs-Simple-Varchars/) looks at performance on the data transmission end.  Keep both in mind and the size of the data you are passing back and forth and how it is going to be used in a query to choose the best approach.